# Python list of tuples to dictionary

Tags: python

In Python 2.7, suppose I have a list with 2 member sets like this

```
d = [(1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3')]
```

What is the easiest way in python to turn it into a dictionary like this:

```
d = {1 : 'value1', 2 : 'value2', 3 : 'value3'}
```

Or, the opposite, like this?

```
d = {'value1' : 1, 'value2': 2, 'value3' : 3}
```

Thanks

Comment: Those are tuples, not sets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dict` constructor can take a sequence. so...

```
dict([(1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3')])
```

and the reverse is best done with a dictionary comprehension

```
{k: v for v,k in [(1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3')]}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your list is in the form of a list of tuples then you can simply use [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

```
In [5]: dict([(1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3')])
Out[5]: {1: 'value1', 2: 'value2', 3: 'value3'}
```

A [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) can be used to construct the reversed dictionary:

```
In [13]: { v : k for (k,v) in [(1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3')] }
Out[13]: {'value1': 1, 'value2': 2, 'value3': 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> lis = [(1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3')]
```

Use `dict()` for the first one:

```
>>> dict(lis)
{1: 'value1', 2: 'value2', 3: 'value3'}
```

And a dict comprehension for the second one:

```
>>> {v:k for k,v in lis}
{'value3': 3, 'value2': 2, 'value1': 1}
```

`dict()` converts an iterable into a dict:

```
>>> print dict.__doc__
dict() -> new empty dictionary
dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
    (key, value) pairs
dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
    d = {}
    for k, v in iterable:
        d[k] = v
dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
    in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [(1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3')]
```

To turn it to dict, just do

```
dict(lst)
```

to reverse it, you can do

```
dict((b,a) for a,b in lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict(my_list)` should probably do the trick. Also, I think you have a list of [tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple), not sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = [(1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3')]
>>> dict(d)
{1: 'value1', 2: 'value2', 3: 'value3'}
>>> dict(map(reversed, d))
{'value3': 3, 'value2': 2, 'value1': 1}
```